# Can't connect to HyperV Guest (Ubuntu) via SSH

Tags: ssh, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

i can't connect to the virtual machine via SSH. The diagram shows the network and it's connections. On the ubuntu-virtual-machine, the SSH-Server is running.
Do i need to enter (with the ubuntu machine) our Windows-Workgroup to get this done? On the windows server machine an inbound rule for port 22 exists an allows connections (i dont know if it is even necessary).

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhyWm.png)
[network adapters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqMHm.png)
[ubuntu port and ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIIEE.png)
[virtual switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNmNg.png)

#### Answers to djomi's questions:

1. yeah, i can ping from guest to host and client/host and client/guest and vice versa
2. ssh on localhost works fine (in VM)
3. see images

[iptables 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY4vS.png)
[iptables 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42lly.png)
[iptables 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHzXr.png)
[iptables 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmfRZ.png)

Comment: can you ping the host, Internet and vise versa from the the vm? ususally it should work in case that the ssh server is installed and active. Check that first try to ssh on the Linux Box itself to See if Theresa a Response and pls list iptables -L - n

Comment: i made changes to my post

Comment: You didn't answer the question if your guest can access the internet (or maybe you don't need to). Check if `sudo ufw allow ssh` in the ubuntu box makes a difference. You don't need an inbound rule in your Hyper-V-host's firewall.

Comment: Ah dude, you saved my day. This rule was not set - works fine now... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your `ufw` installation is not allowing `ssh` connections. You should simply allow them:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```